# NSSpeechRecognizer and .delegate=self; Problems

Tags: objective-c, macos, speech-recognition, osx-elcapitan, appkit

I've run into an issue with this [little Objective-C project](https://github.com/lewisinc/DoorOfDurin) I'm doing and it's proving to be a bit of a roadblock. I'm playing around with Apple's `NSSpeechRecognizer` software on El Capitan, and I'm trying to get this guy running properly so that when the riddle I give it is posed to the user, the user can respond with a word to "do something cool". As it stands right now, the delegate method:

```
-(void) speechRecognizer:(NSSpeechRecognizer *)sender didRecognizeCommand:(NSString *)command { ... }`
```

is never even called, even though it appears the recognition icon is correctly detecting the answer to the riddle.

Comment: Please include the relevant part of your code in your question. I don't see anything using `NSSpeechRecognizer` in the github repository you linked to. (The only code is main.m which is straight from the Xcode template.)

Comment: You are absolutely right. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `main` function has a loop that is continually checking whether the speech has been recognizing. You are not giving `NSSpeechRecognizer` a chance to actually deliver any messages to you.

Your app needs to let the main "run loop" run, so it can deliver messages. Normally, in an OS X app, your `main` would just call `NSApplicationMain`, which does this for you.

Your code is effectively this:

```
@interface RecognizerDelegate : NSObject <NSSpeechRecognizerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) NSSpeechRecognizer *recognizer;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL didRecognize;

@end

@implementation RecognizerDelegate

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.didRecognize = NO;

        self.recognizer = [[NSSpeechRecognizer alloc] init];
        self.recognizer.listensInForegroundOnly = NO;
        self.recognizer.blocksOtherRecognizers = YES;
        self.recognizer.delegate = self;
        self.recognizer.commands = @[ @"hello" ];
        [self.recognizer startListening];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)speechRecognizer:(NSSpeechRecognizer *)sender didRecognizeCommand:(NSString *)command
{
    self.didRecognize = YES;
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        RecognizerDelegate *recognizerDelegate = [[RecognizerDelegate alloc] init];

        while (recognizerDelegate.didRecognize == NO) {
            // do nothing
        }

        NSLog(@"Recognized!");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That `while` loop is doing nothing useful, just running your CPU in a loop and wasting time and energy. You are not letting any other code in `NSSpeechSynthesizer`, or any of the system frameworks like Foundation or AppKit, get the chance to do anything. So, nothing happens.

To fix this in the short term: you can let the main run loop run for a little while in each pass through the loop. This code would let the system run for a second, then would return to your code, so you could check again:

```
while (recognizerDelegate.didRecognize == NO) {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1.0]];
}
```

The longer-term fix would be to move your code out of `main` and to structure it like a real OS X app. Instead of using a loop to poll a condition like `recognizerDelegate.didRecognize`, you would just trigger the "next thing" directly from delegate methods like `-speechRecognizer:didRecognizeCommand:`, or you would use things like `NSTimer` to run code periodically.

For more details, see the Apple doc [Cocoa Application Competencies for OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Devpedia-CocoaApp-MOSX/MainEventLoop.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009448-CH18-SW1), specifically the "Main Event Loop" section.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the thorough explanation. I really need to be more aware of how existing inside of a run-loop affects objects. I suppose my next step is learning how to reorganize everything so that I can simply `return NSApplicationMain(...);` inside of main. I'd like to be able to do it without relying on XCode to set it up for me (inside of vim if preferable :P ), which ironically is why I'm having this issue in the first place! Anyways - thank you, everything works great now.

Comment: @DavidLewis: Great! Since you found this answer useful, please [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using NSSpeechRecognizer. The callback function:

```
func speechRecognizer(_ sender: NSSpeechRecognizer,
                      didRecognizeCommand command: String) {}
```

...was never called, even though everything appeared to be working.

There were three things I changed to get the code working.

1) I had to enable the entitlement in my "sandboxed" mode application to allow for microphone use.

... I also did these other two things, as well.

2) I added the "Privacy - Microphone Usage Description" in the info.pList, and set the string value to "I want to listen to you speak"

3) I added the "Privacy - Speech Recognition Usage Description" in the info.pList, and set the string value to "I want to write down what you say"